# Is it possible to avoid the copy constructor when passing newly created object to a function?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to avoid calling the copy-constructor when passing a just-created object to a function? I don't want to use this object any more, I'd just like to name the temporary and pass it by value to some other function.

I know that in C++11 I can just move this object, but I'm concerned how to improve this in C++03. So essentially, I'm interested in eliminating the copy-constructor call in the code below:

Snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(void) { std::cout << "Default ctr\n"; };
    Foo(const Foo& f) { std::cout << "Copy ctr\n"; }
};

void bar(Foo f)
{
    std::cout << "Inside bar\n";
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    bar(f);
    bar(Foo());
}
```

Possible result:

```
Default ctr
Copy ctr
Inside bar
Default ctr
Inside bar
```

Compilation string:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
```

I.e. to use some kind of copy-elision but on an argument passed to a function, not on a return value (NRVO).

Comment: Why don't you take `f` by `const Foo&` in `bar()` instead?

Comment: ... i.e. `void bar(const Foo& f)`

Comment: I'd like to pass the object by value, the pass by ref is an obvious case. Updated the question - didn't mention the pass by value before, sorry.

Comment: not sure how why you want to you avoid copying when you in effect want to copy by value, it seems illogical. what is the real life use case ?

Comment: @SebastianKramer the words "by-value" implies you have no choice but to copy one way or another. On paper it appears you're trying to solve the very problem move-semantics were introduced to address. There would be a reason such semantics were added to the language: the problem was unsolvable without them.

Comment: Checkout [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/move.html), which allows you to simulate move semantics in C++03. The actual implementation is, shall we say, not pretty.

Comment: Imitating move semantics is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I'll take a look at boost.move, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by value implies copying. This copying can be **elided** but semantically pass by value is still copying. You can pass by reference as well to avoid this copy. Note that these are the only situations in which copy elision are permitted:

- in a return statement
- in a throw-expression
- with a temporary that hasn't been bound to a reference
- and another to do with exceptions

That's why in:

```
bar(f);
bar(Foo());
```

only the second involves copy elision. Pre-C++11, just use a reference or use Boost.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to make sure that this elision is not possible with the core language itself. I'll take a look at the boost lib.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
void bar(const Foo& f)
{
    std::cout << "Inside bar\n";
}
```

The above code passes the object as reference. This effectively copies the address of the object only (like a pointer) but the reference can be handled like the original object.

Comment: I'm interested in passing the object by value.

Comment: @Sebastian: I can't think of a better solution pre C++11. Why is using a reference no solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference(or pointer) of class Foo as parameter to function bar(). This will avoid creation of temporary object, from the object passed as argument to function bar(),and hence no copy constructor will be called.